# How to design custom UI elements in XAF?

Tags: xaf

I'm evaluating XAF for our organization. It seems great and so powerful. But have some problems with its UI customization.

For example, I want to design a PersianDatePicker UI element and tell XAF to use it for DateTime properties.

**Question 1:** How can I design custom UI Elements (like PersianDatePicker) in Web and Win?

**Question 2:** How to tell XAF to use my custom UI controls in the layouts?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can customize built-in DateTime property editors:
   https://documentation.devexpress.com/#eXpressAppFramework/CustomDocument113104
   https://documentation.devexpress.com/#eXpressAppFramework/CustomDocument113114.
2. You can then make them to be used as defaults or to set them in Model where it is appropriate.